CMake Custom Target Configuration Allow Differing Outputs Without Rebuild
I have a custom target for my CMake file that is configurable in the number of output files it produces.  If the caller passes a particular argument to my script, I want to generate more output files.  The issue that I am struggling to resolve is that if the user doesn't pass in the argument to generate more files, and the inputs haven't changed, I want the target to be skipped.
file_generator.sh
#!/bin/bash
touch foo.txt
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    touch bar.txt
fi

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(example VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES )

list(APPEND outputs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.txt)
if (NOT MORE_OUTPUT STREQUAL "")
    list(APPEND outputs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar.txt)
endif()

add_custom_command(
    DEPENDS something.txt
    OUTPUT  ${outputs}
    COMMAND ./file_generator.sh ${MORE_OUTPUT}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/
)
add_custom_target(EXAMPLE ALL DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.txt)

The behavior that I am observing is that the target is run if...

Any inputs have a last modified date after any outputs, or
The command has changed

Is there any way to update this example to prevent running the target if only statement #2 is true (e.g., don't rerun if the command changed, but the outputs are not outdated)?  This is called with either cmake -DMORE_OUTPUT= or cmake -DMORE_OUTPUT=TRUE.

Which build tool (make, ninja) do you use when build the configured project? It is not CMake but a build tool decides whether to run the target or not.

"This is called with either cmake -DMORE_OUTPUT= or cmake -DMORE_OUTPUT=TRUE" - in both cases the check if(DEFINED MORE_OUTPUT) succeed. Instead, when want to disable the option, use cmake -UMORE_OUTPUT.

I am using make as the build tool.  Also updated the question with a corrected if-condition for the MORE_OUTPUT variable.

"The output list has changed" - No, this is not the reason of rebuilding files. The true reason is that CMake deletes the (first) OUTPUT file if COMMAND has been changed. This forces make to run the command again (because one of its output file misses).

@Tsyvarev Corrected the question per your comment.

Is there any way to update this example to prevent running the target if only statement #2 is true so how about just COMMAND if foo.txt is older than something.txt; then do generator; fi in peudocode?

@KamilCuk I don't understand your proposed solution.  How would that enable running file_generator.sh based on the CMake input MORE_OUTPUT?

add_custom_target()'s targets are always out-of-date. see the https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html

have you considered using cmake's configure_file() to generate your file_generator.sh with all the settings it needs, vs. trying to pass around arguments?

I did consider passing the arguments in a file since my build process is Bash->CMake->Bash.  The problem is that I then have to support two interfaces: calling my script with a command-line argument, and passing that command argument in a file.  Seems like there should be a way to get this working in CMake directly, but at this point the answer may just be "no, there isn't a clean way in CMake to accomplish this".
